# How to set JVM options for IntelliJ's RemoteMavenServer?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was playing with `-XX:+CompressedOops` in IntelliJ's `idea.vmoptions` and I noticed that the RemoteMavenServer process started by IntelliJ doesn't use those settings.

Adding the option to the Maven runner settings didn't help either.

Is there any way to configure the RemoteMavenServer JVM options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anton's answer is no longer correct. [IntelliJ 12.0.1](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+12.0.1+Release+Notes) introduced a new UI for configuring the VM arguments of the `RemoteMavenServer` process instead of using `MAVEN_OPTS`:

File -> Settings -> Maven -> Importer -> [VM options for maven import process](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/maven-importing.html#d997046e223)

Answer (score 3):

The `RemoteMavenServer` process will use the JVM options specified in the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable (inherited from the IDEA process).

Please follow: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-60719.

Comment: You mean it uses IDEA process' MAVEN_OPTS?